# Undefined variable error TTS PHP script

Tags: php

I'm trying to make this code work but it won't. Somebody help me please. This is the first file, tts.php:

```
<?php
class TextToSpeech {
    public $mp3data;
    function __construct($text="") {
        $text = trim($text);
        if(!empty($text)) {
            $text = urlencode($text);
            $this->mp3data = file_get_contents("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q={$text}");
        }
    }

    function setText($text) {
        $text = trim($text);
        if(!empty($text)) {
            $text = urlencode($text);
            $this->mp3data = file_get_contents("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q={$text}");
            return $mp3data;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function saveToFile($filename) {
        $filename = trim($filename);
        if(!empty($filename)) {
            return file_put_contents($filename,$this->mp3data);
        } else { return false; }
    }
}
?>
```

Second file, index.php:

```
<?php
require "tts.php";
$tts = new TextToSpeech();
$tts->setText("Hello World!");
$tts->saveToFile("voice.mp3");
?>
```

And this is the error: [image: The error]

*I'm running the code on localhost

Comment: Be aware that Google doesn't like automated requests to the translation service, and you are likely to get blocked or otherwise encounter errors.

Comment: Thank you verry much! I'll use proxies if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return $mp3data;` should be `return $this->mp3data;`

Answer (score 1):

```
return $this->mp3data;
```

instead of

```
return $mp3data;
```

Answer (score 1):

Line 27 is presumably this line in the `setText()` function...

```
return $mp3data;
```

and it should be

```
return $this->mp3data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the row

```
return $mp3data;
```

To

```
return $this->mp3data;
```